# Build tree from formatted input

Tags: rust, tree, queue, borrow-checker

I have been having a problem trying to come up with a solution to read a binary tree from a formatted input and build said tree in Rust. The borrow checker has been driving crazy and thus decided to take to the community.

Basically, the input looks like this:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 N N 7 8
```

and it represents a tree that looks like this:

```
            1
         /     \
        2       3
      /   \   /   \
     4     5 6     N
    / \   /
   N   7 8
```

with N meaning NULL.

To read this, in CPP I would usually read this tree by level doing kind of a Breadth first building of the tree using a queue to do so.
I was attempting the same approach in Rust but that is where hell broke lose on me. I am a beginner in Rust and of course I am being scolded by the borrow checker.

I am using the following TreeNode structure:

```
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq)]
 pub struct TreeNode {
   pub val: i32,
   pub left: Option<Rc<RefCell<TreeNode>>>,
   pub right: Option<Rc<RefCell<TreeNode>>>,
 }

 impl TreeNode {
   #[inline]
   pub fn new(val: i32) -> Self {
     TreeNode {
       val,
       left: None,
       right: None
     }
   }
}
```

And here is the piece of code that is doing the reading of the tree from STDIN:

```
fn read_b_tree<T: io::BufRead>(scan: &mut Scanner<T>, size: usize)
                               -> Result<Option<Rc<RefCell<TreeNode>>>, Box<dyn Error>> {
    if size == 0 {
        Ok(None)
    } else {

        let r = scan.token::<String>();
        if r == "N" {
            Ok(None)
        } else {
            let mut q = VecDeque::new();
            let root = Rc::new(RefCell::new(TreeNode::new(r.parse::<i32>()?)));
            q.push_back(&root);

            let mut cnt: usize = 1;
            while cnt < size && !q.is_empty() {
                let node = match q.pop_front() {
                    Some(node) => Ok(node),
                    _ => Err("Queue should not be empty"),
                }?;

                let v = Rc::clone(node);

                let left = scan.token::<String>();
                let right = scan.token::<String>();

                if left != "N" {
                    let left_n = Rc::new(RefCell::new(TreeNode::new(left.parse::<i32>()?)));
                    v.borrow_mut().left = Some(Rc::clone(&left_n));
                    q.push_back(&left_n);
                }
                cnt += 1;

                if right != "N" {
                    let right_n = Rc::new(RefCell::new(TreeNode::new(right.parse::<i32>()?)));
                    v.borrow_mut().right = Some(Rc::clone(&right_n));
                    q.push_back(&right_n);
                }
                cnt += 1;
            }
            Ok(Some(root))
        }
    }
}
```

As you can imagine, I ran into lifetime issues with this approach, such as:

```
error[E0597]: `right_n` does not live long enough
   --> src/main.rs:146:33
    |
125 |             while cnt < size && !q.is_empty() {
    |                                  - borrow later used here
...
146 |                     q.push_back(&right_n);
    |                                 ^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
147 |                 }
    |                 - `right_n` dropped here while still borrowed
```

I would be highly thankful to anyone who could give some pointers as to how I work out of this situation.

Sincerely,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code is shorter and demonstrates your problem:

```
fn read_b_tree() -> Result<Option<Rc<RefCell<TreeNode>>>, Box<dyn Error>> {
  let r = String::new();
  let mut q = VecDeque::new();
  let root = Rc::new(RefCell::new(TreeNode::new(r.parse::<i32>()?)));
  q.push_back(&root);
  while !q.is_empty() {
    if r != "N" {
      let left_n = Rc::new(RefCell::new(TreeNode::new(r.parse::<i32>()?)));
      q.push_back(&left_n);
    }
  }
  Ok(Some(root))
}
```

The inferred type of q is `VecDeque<&Rc<RefCell<TreeNode>>>`, yet there is no reason why you choose this instead of `VecDeque<Rc<RefCell<TreeNode>>>` (`Rc` instead of `&Rc`) - `Rc` is already a reference so there is no need to do it a second time.

I think you inserted the `&` because without `&` there was an error `use of moved value ...`. This error is correct: You use `root` after moving it to `q`. But that is not a problem, because you wanted to move a `Rc` to `q` and you can easily get one new by just cloning it `root.clone()` or `Rc::clone(&root)`.

The fixed example is:

```
fn read_b_tree() -> Result<Option<Rc<RefCell<TreeNode>>>, Box<dyn Error>> {
  let r = String::new();
  let mut q = VecDeque::new();
  let root = Rc::new(RefCell::new(TreeNode::new(r.parse::<i32>()?)));
  q.push_back(root.clone());
  while !q.is_empty() {
    if r != "N" {
      let left_n = Rc::new(RefCell::new(TreeNode::new(r.parse::<i32>()?)));
      q.push_back(left_n); //this works in the example, but you will have to clone here too
    }
  }
  Ok(Some(root))
}
```

Comment: Thank you that fixed my problem and I learned a little bit more about RC in the process